# Render YAML in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Is there anyway to respond_to a .yml file extension?

I have tried, but can't get it to work.

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.xml # index.xml.builder
      format.yml {render :text => @labels.to_yaml, :content_type => 'text/yaml'}
    end
```

The above code spits out the following error `uninitialized constant Mime::YML`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no need to add that stuff to environment.rb, just change format.yml to format.yaml and it will work.

Comment: I got it to work! Thanks! I also needed to remember that I couldn't pull it up in a browser, only via a web call lol...

Answer (score 3):

Try to add this into your environment.rb file :

```
Mime::Type.register 'text/yaml', :yaml
```

Comment: When I do that I get the following warning message: `already initialized constant YAML`... I am running Rails 3 with Ruby 1.9.2